# I want to fill the comment with the comment count?

Tags: comments

I am using a custom function to pre fill the comment text area with the number of comment count but getting an error header already sent can any body guide me here's the code I am using

```
  add_action('pre_comment_on_post', 'dump_comment');
   function dump_comment($post_id, $author=null, $email=null) {
   $comcnt = $cmntcount = comments_number( '#0', '#1', '#%' );
   $comment = ( isset($_POST['comment']) ) ? trim($_POST['comment']) : null;
   if (!$comment) {
   $_POST['comment'] = 'Design' . '$comcnt';

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason for your *header already sent* error is that you are using

```
comments_number()
```

that will *echo* the value.

Try instead

```
get_comments_number( $post_id );
```

to *return* it.

The Codex info on [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number) function says that it returns the total number of comments, trackbacks, and pingbacks for the post.

Comment: Works like a charm just want to confirm ? if this exclude the trackback and pings ?

Comment: ok great ;-) ps: the Codex says that this will give you the total number of comments, Trackbacks, and Pingbacks for a post